# How to change redirect.jsp to view my custom jsp page instead of index.jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, redirect

Though it is clearly written in index.jsp page of my spring application created in netbeans and running on xampp tomcat, I can't display my custom page.

I have googled, but failed.

Comment: Adding more details(codewise) would be helpful.

Comment: It is the skeleton project created by netbeans. In redirect.jsp it has   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% response.sendRedirect("index.htm"); %> And web.xml has 
         ....
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

Answer (score 3):

Defined your custom login form in Spring XML file. See explanation below :

`login-page=”/login”` – The login form will be `“/login”`

`default-target-url=”/welcome”` – If authentication success, forward to `“/welcome”`

`authentication-failure-url=”/loginfailed”` – If authentication failed, forward to

```
“/loginfailed”
```

`logout-success-url=”/logout”` – If logout , forward to `“/logout”`

below is the code to config code that needs  to be written in `spring-security.xml`

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems my problem is solved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770240/how-to-put-jsp-files-in-a-separate-folder